# Mock UIViewController defined in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, testing, uiviewcontroller, mocking

I have a UIViewController-class instantiated via Storyboard that contains a constant property. For testing, I want to replace/mock whatever the value of the view controller.

I can actually do this by subclassing and defining a new constant and by overriding the methods that use it. However, I do not know how to instantiate the ViewController, since it's not in the storyboard.

It's important that all views and all other functionality of the original ViewController is still present, of course. How to go about it?

Comment: Any luck in finding an answer/solution to this?. I have also tried using swizzling and objc_setClass, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you need to access a property from another ViewController outside your Storyboard without presenting it. Since you're using swift, all you need to do is instantiate the class itself i believe. For example if the ViewController that is not in the storyboard has a class named "SecondController", and the variable inside second controller is called "stringVar" then all you need to do is this:

```
var secondVC = SecondController()
secondVC.stringVar = "new string value"
```

Example:

```
//SecondVC

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var something:String! = "String Value";
}


//Main VC

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var secondVC = SecondViewController()
        secondVC.something = "Another String Value"
        println(secondVC.something)

    }

 }
```

Comment: Hm, I get "Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call" if I do this. Furthermore, it's a constant that I assign directly at declaration in the subclass.

Comment: have you implemented initWithCoder in the secondVC?, because i just tried it and it worked

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I forgot to state that I need to implement an initializer that requires a coder: NSCoder object to be passed. How can I create a valid coder-object?

Comment: i believe you can pass **nil** as a coder, so it would be `var secondVC = SecondViewController(coder: nil)` i don't know if that will do it for you tho

Comment: nil doesn't work, new NSCoder() neither: "*** -decodeObjectForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!"  - I think I'll skip trying this for now. Thank you for your time!